# Automatically jump outside bracket on IntelliJ IDEA for Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

How can I automatically jump out of closing brackets in Dart?
It's working with Tab in Java, but unfortunately not in Dart.
"Jump outside closing bracket/quote with Tab" in enabled in Settings.

[image: Jump not working]

Answer (score 0):

Please vote for [WEB-33657](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33657/Jump-outside-closing-quote-with-tab-should-work-with-dart-imports) to raise its priority and get notified on updates